# PROBLEMA ANDROID usando la libreria Volley no inserta los datos en mi Mysql del servidor

Tags: php, java, mysql, android, volley

Es una descripción breve estoy empezando con android y estoy intentando insertar datos el mi servidor web mediante un script PHP que lo probé solo y funciona perfecto..

el echo es que ejecuto la app en mi dispositivo y entra en onResponse de la libreria Volley pero es como si llegara hasta allí porque no ejecuta el script php ni los mensajes que tengo en el escript.. y obvio no inserta los datos en mi tabla mysql..

cabe destacar que estoy en servidor gratuito para probar específicamente en freehosting también lo probre con XAM y tampoco.

también tengo el permiso de Internet

y la etiqueta para que me habilite el http solo android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

y la libreria que usu implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

Este es mi Activity.java

```
package com.rrvq.servidor2webmysql;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etnombre, etprecio, etfabricante;

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        etnombre = findViewById(R.id.etproducto);
        etprecio = findViewById(R.id.etprecio);
        etfabricante = findViewById(R.id.etfabricante);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                ejecutarServicio("http://MIDIRECCION.COM/registrar.php");
            }
        });

    }

    private void ejecutarServicio(String URL){


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                // el problema es que entra aca PERO NO INSERTA NADA EN LA BASE DE DATOS MYSQL DE MI SERVIDOR
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operacion Exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                String e = error.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();

                String nom = etnombre.getText().toString();
                String pre = etprecio.getText().toString();
                String fa = etfabricante.getText().toString();

                parametros.put("producto", nom);
                parametros.put("precio", pre);
                parametros.put("fabricante", fa);


                return parametros;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


}
```

Este es mi scrit php registrar.php (cabe destacar que ya lo probe con valores por defecto y el scrip insrta datos perfecto el problema es desde android (bueno pienso yo que no llama o ejecuta el script)

```js
<?php


//free hosting
$servername = "Nombre del servidor";
$database = "nombre de base de datos";
$username = "usuario";
$password = "pass";

// Create connection
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conexion) {
    die("Conexion Fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$producto = $_POST['producto'];
$precio = $_POST['precio'];
$fabricante = $_POST['fabricante'];

// esto es en caso que lo desee pero ahora el codifo lo puse auto incrementable
if (empty($producto)) {

    exit("Debe Ingresar el codigo para validar el registro");
    # code...
}

$consulta = "INSERT INTO productos (producto,precio,fabricante) VALUES ('$producto','$precio','$fabricante')";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);


if($result){
    echo "Datos ingresados";
}else{
    echo "Error al ingresar Datos";
    echo "Error: " . $result . "<br>" . $conexion->error;
}


mysqli_close($conexion);





?>
```

Comment: sucede en cualquier Android api?? checa estas respuestas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: gracias amigo.. creo que era tema se hosting.. me cambie de hosting y funciona a la parfeccion..